# How to Level Concrete for Sliding Patio Doors?

Tags: concrete, outdoor, vinyl

I'm replacing an outdoor sliding patio door set with a new one that has almost the exact same dimensions - luckily the previous homeowner (family) did not go with custom-sized doors.

The issue is that the door will reside over three concrete slabs - the patio itself was installed piecemeal through the years, so toward the inside there are two slabs that meet 2/3 of the way through the jambway, and on the other side is a brand new slab that I poured last year myself (Quikrete, replaced a set of about 15 thin patio stones on top of dirt).

While the concrete that I poured is passable (isn't completely level), there is a big gap at the meeting of both slabs (the corner of the one seemed to break off - so about 5 inches from the gap there's a tad of a hump).

The new patio door set I ordered has about a 4" jamb, so that's about how wide I'd need to level. How do I level this so my new doors aren't all cattywampus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your door with available shimming it in place then use a 4000 psi rated NON SHRINK grout this will harden and will not allow the door to move .be sure its non shrink use a small trowel  to push to grout under the jam  don't try and get away with only using your hands the trial will help you make sure you have no air bubble so there will be no room for water to fill small voids and freeze causing separation good luck